# How to wrap template using ngForTemplate?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I try to make ListView component using `ngForTemplate` for custom templates

**list-view.component.html**

```
<div class="list-view">
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="items" [ngForTemplate]="template">
    </template>
</div>
```

**list-view.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'm-list-view',
    styleUrls: ['./list-view.component.less'],
    templateUrl: './list-view.component.html'
})

export class ListViewComponent {
    @Input() items: any[] = [];

    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    template: any;
}
```

When I use it like this:

```
<m-list-view [items]="categories">
    <template let-item="$implicit">
        **some HTML markup**
    </template>
</m-list-view>
```

the resulting is:

```
<m-list-view>
    <div class="list-view">
        **some HTML markup**
        **some HTML markup**
        **some HTML markup**
        ...
    </div>
</m-list-view>
```

but I need this:

```
<m-list-view>
    <div class="list-view">
        <div class="list-view-item">**some HTML markup**</div>
        <div class="list-view-item">**some HTML markup**</div>
        <div class="list-view-item">**some HTML markup**</div>
        ...
    </div>
</m-list-view>
```

What should I do to wrap each list view item template in div.list-view-item?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

It is now advised that you use the following syntax:

```
<div class="list-view">
  <div class="list-view-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: item">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

```
<div class="list-view">
  <div class="list-view-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="item"></template>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not what I was asking for. I need template to be wrapped in `div.list-view-item` within `ListViewComponent`, without specifying it manually. In other words, it should be done by `ListViewComponent` itself.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: _TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined_. 
`<m-list-view [items]="categories"><template let-item="$implicit">{{item.title}}</template></m-list-view>`

Comment: I changed `$implicit` to `{ item: item }` and now it works as expected!

Comment: Then you would not need to change $implicit: `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="list-view-item">
                <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-container>`